# Required Windows installer for "Geoserver 2.15.2"

Tags: geoserver

Checking latest version of GeoServer 2.15.2 & found that Windows installer is not available

However "war" file option is available ,also downloaded "Platform Independent Binary" but it looks like pure Windows installer is not available as of now OR changed their deployment strategy for Windows not sure.

Does anyone know?

Comment: You are right, the GeoServer project can't deliver Windows installer at the moment because the Windows build server was lost.

Comment: We seem to get the installer only for versions upto 2.14.2
http://geoserver.org/release/2.14.2/ Andrea, thanks for the clarification But could you explain why WAR deployment is better suited for production? I am right now using the platform independent binary, would you recommend it for production instead?

Comment: Because the Jetty container used in the installer has been setup to be a minimal demo and lacks large part of a full Jetty installation. It is also limited to 32 bit when running as a service, which severely limits RAM that can be given to GeoServer. For production we use a full Tomcat installation, setup as a service, and deploy GeoServer in it instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GeoServer project lost the Windows build server that was used to build the installer, there is a desire to get one back but no deadline to have it. The build server in question must be secured as it will have to host a private certificate to sign the installers.

If you have funding to get such private server going please get in contact with the [GeoServer developer list](http://geoserver.org/devel/).

It is to be noted that the Windows installer produced a setup that meant for demo and tests, but not best suited for production. For production environment a Tomcat installation with the GeoServer WAR deploy is recommended instead.