# Windows installer for GeoServer 2.15.4

Tags: geoserver, installation, windows-10

I am trying to find a windows installer for GeoServer.
Could not find it :(

Does anyone know where to find it or how to set up GeoServer on Windows using Platform independent binaries or is there another way to set it up?

I tried going to this page but could not locate windows installer.
http://geoserver.org/release/maintain/

I have used GeoServer earlier but at that time I was able to find a windows installer. Not sure if GeoServer has stopped providing windows installer.

Comment: Unfortunately the GeoServer project cannot build deliverable Windows installers at the moment. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331485/required-windows-installer-for-geoserver-2-15-2. You can workaround the certificate problem by building your own installer  https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/win-installer.html. IMHO the advantage of using the installer compered to bin-zip or WAR installation is minimal. For bin-zip installation read https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/win_binary.html (partly old). In short: download, unzip, and run the "startup.bat".

Comment: Thanks @user30184, it works fine after unzip and running startup.bat. Just had to set environment variables like JAVA_HOME, GEOSERVER_HOME and GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR to relevant paths. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer has indeed stopped providing Windows installers. The community is looking for resources to setup a secured Windows machine where the installer can be built and the OSGeo certificate applied to it (otherwise Windows would complain during installation about unidentified provider).

If anyone reading this message can provide such environment, please contact the GeoServer developer list: http://geoserver.org/devel/

Comment: Thanks @Andrea Aime. It was helpful.